# Google CDN not sending jQuery gzipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, gzip

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003596/google-cdn-not-gzipping-jquery), but the answer didn't help me. I tried [Rex Swain's excellent HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) and his tool does indeed receive it gzipped, but I don't. Anyway, here's the header details from Google's own Chrome:-

[image: Google API jQuery request headers/response]

Does anyone have *any* idea why Google is not sending jQuery gzipped here?

Comment: Sends it gzip-ed to me. To be fair, it's Google's prerogative to serve traffic from their servers any way they like. Strangely, I don't get a 302 response for 1.5.1, but I do for 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe behind a proxy which is either stripping off the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` from your request, or just de-gzipping the response?

Comment: No - I have my own cookieless static content server domain that is serving all gzipped JS and CSS fine and dandy. Just the Goog that isn't playing ball.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are seeing `ContentLength: 85260`? Chrome basically shows the uncompressed size and hence you're seeing this.

I would recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or even you can see it in [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com), and don't worry Google's jQuery CDN gives you **gzipped** response as long as `Accept-Encoding: gzip` property in request header.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm seeing the compressed size in Chrome:
`Content-Encoding:gzip`, `Content-Length:33321`

Comment: You are right, I had fiddler on which decoded before it sent to Chrome. My bad

Comment: I'm using the Network tab in Chrome's developer tools and comparing the 'size' and 'content' - it's definitely Google not sending gzipped content for that version of jQuery to me personally for some reason. Gawd know what...

Comment: Have you tried for `v1.5.2`. Because, I have been testing on this stackoverflow page, and stackoverflow uses `v1.5.2` and it is returning gzipped reponse. Try to put this on: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Bah - it looks like Google is being 'selective' in what it does and doesn't send gzipped - regardless of the `Accept-Encoding` header that is sent. Et voila (note the higher jQuery version number):

[image]

Will have to do some testing to make sure this higher version of jQuery works OK with my app...

Comment: What happens if you try 1.5.2? Might be less of a leap than 1.7.0. Also smaller.

Comment: Google does not appear to serve jQuery versions 1.4.2, 1.4.4 or 1.5.1 gzipped. Why? Search me...